# Qual è il significato di "beneficio" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La chimera*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto queste parole, che vengono pronunciate da un vescovo del Seicento:

> In quella chiesa poi non solo una cappella vi fu costituita, ma anche un **beneficio** per dirvi Messa, et in molte altre chiese per la diocesi si vedono altari et immagini della Panacea.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "beneficio" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire cosa significa nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 1):

Fa riferimento al diritto ecclesiastico:

> Un  [beneficio ecclesiastico](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beneficio_ecclesiastico) è un istituto giuridico risalente ai tempi del feudalesimo, attribuito alle proprietà fondiarie ed immobiliari che si concedevano ai chierici in usufrutto per compenso dei loro uffici e, alla morte del fruttuario, ritornavano alla Chiesa cattolica.
>
> Una forma particolare acquistava il beneficio ecclesiastico con il diritto di patronato. Con tale diritto coloro che dotavano un altare o una cappella, disponevano anche del beneficiato, per lo più i preti di famiglia o di coloro che appartenevano al ramo, e potevano trasformare il beneficio a loro piacere e giudizio.

In questo caso può far riferimento ad un altare.

Comment: Scusa, ma continuo a non capire bene: quello che si costruisce per dire messa sarebbe una proprietà immobiliare concessa ai chierici in usufrutto?

Comment: Sospetto che fosse un beneficio *per pagare un prete* per dirvi messa

Comment: Penso sia un’estensione del significato della parola “beneficio” da diritto a luogo. Il diritto ecclesiastico è molto complesso. Roba da esperti.